# How to prevent client from changing objectify @ID in Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: java, rest, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I am using objectify to persist objects to Google Cloud datastore. The "primary key" is annotated with @Id.

```
@Entity
class Car {
    @Id Long id;
    ...
}
```

I generate the client endpoint (using Android Studio).

I need getters and setters for all fields, including id, so that REST is able to serialize and deserialize the object. If I don't add getters and setters, then these are created by the Google endpoint builder.

Normally, the client GETs an instance from datastore, changes attributes and UPDATEs it back. The backend processes the new attributes and stores them in datastore.

As long as the id is the same, this works as supposed. But what happens when the client changes the id? Because the server is stateless, it believes another object has been updated and either inserts or updates the wrong object. In other words, if the new id already exists in datastore, then that record is updated; if it doesn't exist then a new record with that id is created.

This behavior is inherent to datastore, but this will mess up the database if the client ever changes the id, so there must be a way to prevent this.

I can see two solutions:

1. As suggested here [GAE - Getter without Setter - How to prevent client from writing a given property? How to prevent client from modifying the object ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686429/gae-getter-without-setter-how-to-prevent-client-from-writing-a-given-propert) by @zgc7009, I could leave the setter empty and let it do nothing. I have tried this and it works, as long as there are no related objects.
2. I could use a version field on the backend, which I increment each time UPDATE is called. This allows me to verify if client version == server version - 1 and throw an exception if not. This measure would reduce chances of updating the wrong record, but it would require a read from the datastore before each write and therefore isn't efficient.

As both solutions are not nice, I believe somebody at Google has been thinking about this and there must be a better way to ensure data integrity across REST. Due to my understanding - and I don't know if that can be changed -, Google Endpoints API is generated in a way where the id is not included within the URL, or this happens under the cover. In other words: Normally the id under which an object is stored is included with the URL (metadata). Here, it is included with the object (payload) and can therefore be changed by the client.

Can anybody shed light please?

PS: I know that best practices for datastore in above example would probably using the VIN as id, but this is not always possible. There are objects where no unique identifier can be created for use as id.

Comment: Why would the client ever need to change the Id? Can you come up with a good scenario of why it would need to?

Comment: The client **should** never change the Id, but my questions was about what would happen if it does change it. It **can** change it because REST is stateless and the client can change any property.

Comment: You have to do server side checks.  How do you prevent someone from doing anything malicious?

Comment: So I wasn't clear in my last post.  The rest format is simple strings.  The presence/abscense of a getter doesn't prevent anyone from changing the ID.  It's an illusion of safety.  The server must ensure permissions and if someone wants to write bad data you need to find ways to isolate the damage to the account or put in safety checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a common problem many have faced. There is one thing you can do:

*Your solution 2 above is a good one but you're worried about reading from the `Datastore` before each write*. This can be mitigated by annotating your entity class with `@Cache` so that the first time a client retrieves entities they will be cached. This way when the client calls your backend to update or do whatever you will not hit the `Datastore` when comparing the versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about exposing sensitive attributes over your endpoint you have 2 alternatives:

1) annotate them (getters) with `@ApiResourceProperty(ignored=AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)` so the endpoints serializer skips them.

2) Don't send your entities over the API, create basic POJOs with only the fields you want/need to transfer.